# Python PyQT4 - Adding an unknown number of QComboBox widgets to QGridLayout

Tags: python, pyqt, qcombobox, qlistview

I want to retrieve a list of people's names from a queue and, for each person, place a checkbox with their name to a QGridLayout using the addWidget() function. I can successfully place the items in a QListView, but they just write over the top of each other rather than creating a new row. Does anyone have any thoughts on how I could fix this?

```
self.chk_People = QtGui.QListView()
items = self.jobQueue.getPeopleOffQueue()

for item in items:
    QtGui.QCheckBox('%s' % item, self.chk_People)
```

self.jobQueue.getPeopleOffQueue() would return something like ['Bob', 'Sally', 'Jimmy'] if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
QtGui.QCheckBox('%s' % item, self.chk_People)
```

Doesn't add the check box to the list view, it only creates it with the list view as the parent, and there's a big difference.

The simplest way to use a list view is the `QListWidget` convenience class. For that, create your checkboxes as instances of `QListWidgetItem` and then use `addItem` on the list widget to really add them to it.

Did you have a problem adding them to a grid layout? Usually, if the amount of checkboxes you have is small a grid layout might be better - it all depends on how you want your app to look. But if you might have a lot of such objects, then a list widget/view is the best.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you the solution in PyQt but the structure you need to follow is the following. The QListView can do what you need, you don't need to create separate checkboxes. Create a subclass of [`QAbstractItemModel`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qabstractitemmodel.html) or [`QStandardItemModel`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qstandarditemmodel.html) (depending on how much coding you will want to do) override the `flags()` method to return the appropriate flags *including* [`Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.1/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum), in the `columncount()` method add an extra column to include the checkbox and in the `data` method for the column where you want your checkbox to appear return the checked state `Qt::Checked`, `Qt::Unchecked` for the  `Qt::CheckStateRole`.

This can also be accomplished using the [`QListWidget`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qlistwidget.html) where you can use [`QListWidgetItem`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qlistwidgetitem.html) for adding data and do not need to create a model. On `QListWidgetItem` you can use `setFlags()` and `setData(QVariant(bool, Qt::CheckStateRole)` without having to subclass a model